# Asynchronous requests

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I have a modal which will show a list of `campos`, so I do a GET request for the list and only filter the `campos` in my JSON. 
The problem is that the request is taking too long to respond and it just opens the modal without the ready data. 
 How do I get the JS wait until the for loop end all interactions and then open the modal? I try use *$q*

```
$scope.novoCampo = function (index) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        contatosAPI.getDados().then(function (response) {
            var campos = [];
            var listaContatos = response.data._embedded.contatos;
            for (var i = 0; i < listaContatos.length; i++) {
                var dados = listaContatos[i].dados;
                for (var j = 0; j < dados.length; j++) {
                    var nomeCampo = dados[j].campo;
                    if (campos.indexOf <= -1) {
                        campos.push(nomeCampo);
                    }
                }
            }
            deferred.resolve(campos);
        }).catch(function (error) {
            alert("Erro ao obter os campos!");
            console.log(error + "\t" + JSON.stringify(error));
            deferred.reject(status);
        });

        deferred.promise.then(function (listaCampos) {
            //Here in my console.log is empty 
            console.log("lista " + '\t' + JSON.stringify(listaCampos) + '\t' + listaCampos[0]);
            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
                templateUrl: 'novoCampo.html',
                controller: 'novoCampoController',
                size: '',
                resolve: {
                    index: function () {
                        return index
                    }
                }
            });

            modalInstance.result.then(function (result) {
                try {
                    $scope.contatos[result.index].dados.push({
                        campo: result.nomeCampo,
                        valor: ""
                    });
                } catch (error) {
                    alert("Erro ao inserir novo campo!");
                }
            }, function () {
                $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
            });
        }, function (reject) {
            alert("erro" + reject);
        });

    };
```

Comment: You use the [deferred anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern) here, so maybe the problem comes from a timeout in contatosAPI.getDados() (see my answer below). A timeout results in an error but the error is not propagated to the caller of contatosAPI.getDados() so the catch callback is not executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you use the $http service in contatosAPI.getDados function. You can set a timeout parameter manually in the configuration of your request so that it doesn't end too early. See [Angular documentation of $http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: In fact the problem was in the code , take a look at it `campos.indexOf <= -1`

Comment: oh I see ! Hard to see... Good to know you solved you issue :) So at least you know what to do if you have a timeout issue later.